# Custom Cell Labels in UITableView Does Not Populate

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

On my storyboard is a Tab Bar Controller with two view controllers.  The first view controller has a UITableView, and the second view controller is used to collect data which will be displayed in table view format on the first view controller.

For this, I have created four swift files:

1. TARISKTREATMENT.swift - contains the class TARISKTREATMENT that's linked to the first view controller (the one with the UITableView)
2. TAADDRISKTREATMENT.swift - contains the class TAADDRISKTREATMENT that's linked to the second view controller.
3. TREATMENTS.swift - Struct that's used to collect data entered on second view controller.
4. CUSTOMTREATMENTCELL.swift - UITableViewCell class for the custom cell.

The second view controller collects the data from the user perfectly, and when I run print commands, I can see that the data is actually in the struct.

For some reason, the code from TARISKTREATMENT.swift does not populate the custom cell.

What am I doing wrong here?

CODE:  TARISKTREATMENT.swift  (View controller 1 with UITableView - the one that's not working...)

```
import UIKit

class TARISKTREATMENT: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var TreatmentsTableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        TreatmentsTableView.dataSource = self
        TreatmentsTableView.delegate = self
        TreatmentsTableView.reloadData()

    }//END - viewDidLoad

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return TreatmentsManager.newTreatments.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let IndividualCell = TreatmentsTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TreatmentCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CUSTOMTREATMENTCELL

        IndividualCell.outletLabel_TreatmentPackageName.text = TreatmentsManager.newTreatments[indexPath.row].varTreatmentPackageName

        IndividualCell.outletLabel_TreatmentDescription.text = TreatmentsManager.newTreatments[indexPath.row].varTreatmentPackageDetail

        IndividualCell.outletLabel_TreatmentResponsiblePerson.text = TreatmentsManager.newTreatments[indexPath.row].varTreatmentResponsiblePerson

        IndividualCell.outletLabel_TreatmentDTGCompleted.text = String(TreatmentsManager.newTreatments[indexPath.row].varTreatmentDTGCompleted)

        let varSelectPriorityPic = TreatmentsManager.newTreatments[indexPath.row].varTreatmentPriority

        switch varSelectPriorityPic {   
        case "HIGH":
            IndividualCell.outletImage_TreatmentPriority.image = imageTreatmentPriorityHigh
        case "MEDIUM":
            IndividualCell.outletImage_TreatmentPriority.image = imageTreatmentPriorityMedium
        case "LOW":
            IndividualCell.outletImage_TreatmentPriority.image = imageTreatmentPriorityLow
        default:
            break
        }
        return IndividualCell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){
        if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete){

            TreatmentsManager.newTreatments.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
            TreatmentsTableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

CODE:  TREATMENTS.swift

```
import UIKit

var TreatmentsManager: classTreatmentsManager = classTreatmentsManager()

struct structTreatment {
    var varTreatmentPackageName : String
    var varTreatmentPackageDetail : String
    var varTreatmentResponsiblePerson : String
    var varTreatmentPriority : String
    var varTreatmentDTGCompleted : NSDate
}

class classTreatmentsManager: NSObject {

    var newTreatments = [structTreatment]()

    func funcAddTreatment(varTreatmentPackageName: String, varTreatmentPackageDetail: String, varTreatmentResponsiblePerson: String, varTreatmentPriority: String, varTreatmentDTGCompleted: NSDate){

        newTreatments.append(structTreatment(varTreatmentPackageName: varTreatmentPackageName, varTreatmentPackageDetail: varTreatmentPackageDetail, varTreatmentResponsiblePerson: varTreatmentResponsiblePerson, varTreatmentPriority: varTreatmentPriority, varTreatmentDTGCompleted: varTreatmentDTGCompleted))
    }
}
```

CODE:  CUSTOMTREATMENTCELL.swift

```
import UIKit

class CUSTOMTREATMENTCELL: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var outletImage_TreatmentPriority: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var outletLabel_TreatmentPackageName: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var outletLabel_TreatmentDescription: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var outletLabel_TreatmentResponsiblePerson: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var outletLabel_TreatmentDTGCompleted: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
}
```

I've uploaded a small video to show what's (not) happening [here](https://youtu.be/4OeI8pd9UWU).

Your assistance is appreciated - thanks!

Comment: Hi @Jaco I suspect the probelm is the tableview dataSource is empty. would you verify that `TreatmentsManager.newTreatments.count` is not `0`

Comment: Hi @Ismail - verified.  The count increases everytime the user clicks the Save button.  I've printed TreatmentsManager.newTreatment and even when multiple instances of data have been entered, everything is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is fine in your code. What you miss is reloading the data :

```
 override func viewWillAppear() {
    super.viewWillAppear()
    TreatmentsTableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Fabulous!  That's what was needed.  Thanks @Ismail!